# Почему не работает событие play()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Написал такой скрипт.

Предполагается, что при нажатии на кнопку voice-btn, в зависимости от ее id должен рандомно воспроизводиться один из 3х звуков. Но что-то ничего не работает, подскажите где я ошибся?

```js
//Deer sounds
let deer1 = new Audio('sounds/deer1.mp3');
let deer2 = new Audio('sounds/deer2.mp3');
let deer3 = new Audio('sounds/deer3.mp3');
//Fox sounds
let fox1 = new Audio('sounds/fox1.mp3');
let fox2 = new Audio('sounds/fox2.mp3');
let fox3 = new Audio('sounds/fox3.mp3');
//Voice random selection
function randomVoice() {
    let rand = 1 + Math.random() * (4 - 1);
    return Math.floor(rand);
}
//playingNow - воспроизводится ли звук
let playingNow = false;
//При нажатии на кнопку воспроизведения звука
//Определяем на какую именно кнопу нажали (currentAnimal)
//Рандомно выбираем номер звука 1-3 (voiceNumber)
$('.voice-btn').click(function () {
    let currentAnimal = $(this).attr('id');
    let voiceNumber = randomVoice();
    if (!playingNow){
        switch (voiceNumber) {
            case 1:
                playVoice(currentAnimal + '1');
                break;
            case 2:
                playVoice(currentAnimal + '2');
                break;
            case 3:
                playVoice(currentAnimal + '3');
                break;
        }
        playingNow = true;
    }
    //Воспроизводит выбранный выше звук
    function playVoice(voice) {
        voice.play();
    }
    //Если один из звуков завершился
    //разрешаем воспроизводить другой
    (currentAnimal + '1').onended = function() {
        playingNow = false
    };
    (currentAnimal + '2').onended = function() {
        playingNow = false
    };
    (currentAnimal + '3').onended = function() {
        playingNow = false
    };
});
```

```css
.voice-btn{
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="voice-btn" id="deer">Олень</div>
<div class="voice-btn" id="fox">Лиса</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас вот тут получается строка

```
let currentAnimal = $(this).attr('id');
```

к ней прибавляется строка

```
currentAnimal + '1'
```

а потом вот тут вы пытаетесь вызвать метод play() у этой строки

```
voice.play();
```

само собой у строки (voice="deer1") нет такого метода

Как я понимаю вы предполагали что ваша строка (на пример "deer1") "превратиться" в имя переменной, и у этой переменной вызовется метод play().
По идее такое сделать можно, как вот тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613834/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-javascript

Но в вашем случае лучше переложить Audio объекты из обычных переменных в какую нибудь структуру данных на пример

1) массив объектов

```
let sounds = [{name:"deer1", audio: new Audio('sounds/deer1.mp3')}]
```

получать вот так

```
sounds.find(x => x.name === "deer1").audio.play()
```

2) или в объект

```
let sounds = {"deer1": new Audio('sounds/deer1.mp3')}
```

получать вот так

```
sounds["deer1"].play()
```